# How can I solve this - styling two lists

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a website for a virtual airline. I have a list styled for my topnav div, however I want just the usual list for another div I'm using. This another div I want to use are jQuery tabs. Trouble is, it's calling the list defines from the .usual, which is the main div for the jQuery tabs, so my list has no dots, and does not function like a list, being in a single line and breaking the format.

```
.usual li { 
    list-style:none; 
    float:left; 
}
```

HTML...

```
<div class="usual">
  <ul class="idTabs">
    <li><a href="#idTab1" class="selected">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#idTab2">Recruitment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#idTab3">Management</a></li>
    <li><a href="#idTab4">Operating Procedures</a></li>
    <li><a href="#idTab5">Airline Rules & Policies</a></li>
  </ul>

    <div class="pilot_handbook" id="idTab1">
    <p>Hello there</p>

    <br/>
    <div class="msg-yellow"><strong>Tip:</strong> Navigate the handbook by the tabs on the top. These allow you to access different sections of the handbook.</div>
    <br/>

    </div>

    <div class="pilot_handbook" id="idTab2">
    <p><strong>1.1 Testing<br />
  </strong><br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<ul class="basic_list">
  <li>Testing 1</li>
  <li>Testing 2</li>
  <li>Testing 3</li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

Then I tried clearing the style on the .usual li by making a class on the ul, and doing this. It doesn't however work, and I'm slightly lost...

```
.basic_list {
    list-style-type: circle;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: A fiddle for css question is **mandatory**!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
.usual li { ... }
```

Use:

```
.idTabs li { ... }
```

Since it is more specific to the region you want to style.

Comment: .usual li styles the jQuery tabs, which you click. So if I change it, the tabs will be vertical and messed up.

Comment: I changed another div to set the padding and margin on the tabs and it actually worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your `<div class='usual'>` isn't closed.

Edit for clarity:
Your div.usual encompasses both lists, so they are getting the style you set for lists inside .usual. Either change your style for just the one div or move the second list outside the div.usual

Comment: It is, sorry, I've missed a tag on here. I'll add it so I won't confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the class `idTabs` in your selector:

```
.usual .idTabs li { 
    list-style:none; 
    float:left; 
}
```